# Reduce logging for health-checks

Tags: nginx

I want Nginx to log less when it's serving a health-check, but I'm not able to silence it as much as I expect. I'd like help finding the bug in my configuration.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
daemon off;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /dev/stderr debug;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    upstream api {
        server api.local;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api;
            location /health {
                # health checks are frequent and boring, so we avoid logging them
                access_log off;
                error_log /dev/stderr error;
                proxy_pass http://api;
             }
             location /users {
                proxy_pass http://api;
                # other stuff ...
             }
             # other locations ...
         }
    }
}
```

When Kubernetes probes it with a `livenessProbe`, I get a series of lines like

> 2016/08/30 19:50:32 [info] 7#0: *1 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.2.29.0, server: 0.0.0.0:80

Since I'm asking for `error` level inside of the `/health` location, I thought I wouldn't see this info-level message. How can I silence it?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can have sub-locations like that, or at least it's not recommended. Try moving them to the server section?

Comment: You can and it works (in that I see the access log for `/users` but not `/health`). Do you think that it works for the `access_log` directive but not for `error_log`?

Answer (score 4):

Location should not be nested.

```
server 
{

location / {
            proxy_pass http://api;
         }

location /health {
# health checks are frequent and boring, so we avoid logging them
                access_log off;
                error_log /dev/stderr error;
                proxy_pass http://api;
         }

location /users {
                proxy_pass http://api;
                # other stuff ...
         }

}
```

Comment: Can you add more detail? Do you mean that the logging directives only work on a top-level location? (Location normally can be nested: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)